# credit card function errors, python: 'list' object has no attribute keys

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working from a file import, where the input is a list of numbers

so one function feeds into another, first printing list/reading text file, second function validating if credit card is valid/invalid acc to `regex`, and then creating a dictionary and printing summary.

```
y = {}

def credit_card_validator(numbers):

    for number in numbers:
    result = re.findall (insert regex, number)
        if result == []:
           y[xx] = 'invalid'
        else:
           y[xx] = 'valid'
    return numbers



def print_credit_card_summary(y):
    for numbers in dict_o:
       print(numbers+'     ' + y[numbers])
    return y
```

But  I have two errors:

> Error (credit_card_validator()): 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

and:

> Error (print_credit_card_summary()): list indices must be integers or
>   slices, not str

How can I fix this code and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but your for loop indentation is off.

Comment: You are passing a list to the `print_credit_card_summary` function. Where do you call it? Please post all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1 : Right off the bat, there is an indentation error in function `credit_card_validator`'s for loop. Solving this might solve the problem because I see no `keys` used for the list object.

Error 2 : The value in `numbers` used to address elements from `dict_o` is not an integer value. Always the indices of lists must be integers. Try `dict_o[whatever_array_numbers_is_linked_to.index(numbers)]`? This might work.